# Combine two multi line strings in python

Tags: python

I have two strings currently, lets say they are

1
2
3
4
5

and

a
b
c
d
e

I want the strings to be combined into

1a
2b
3c
4d
5e

How would I go about doing this in python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your effort

Comment: [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.split); [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip); [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join)

Comment: Are these list of strings or just strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some comprehension with `zip`, `split`, and `join`:

```py
'\n'.join(f'{x}{y}' for x,y in zip(string1.split('\n'), string2.split('\n')))
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
1a
2b
3c
4d
5e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the code below:

```
str1 = "1\n2\n3\4\n5" 
str2 = "a\nb\nc\nd\ne"
# \n means new line in python 
lst1 = str1.split("\n")
lst2 = str2.split("\n")
result_lst = [] 
for i, j in zip(lst1, lst2):
   result_lst.append(i + j)
new_line = "\n" 
result_str = new_line.join(result_lst)
print(result_str)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
1a
2b
3c
4d
5e
```